# Does a bag carried out to the escape count as a secured bag?

Tags: payday-3

If I carry a bag out to the escape, rather than securing it in a helicopter or what have you (depending on the heist), does that bag count as a bag stolen at the end? Or do I need to throw the loot into the van or helicopter before escaping to get credit for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, if you carry a bag out to the escape, that bag does count towards the total at the end of the heist. You do not need to specifically throw the bag into a vehicle, just carrying it at the escape is sufficient. This includes any bags carried by bots.